# Trying to Call An Api on Success will get the Data, But on Failure it Dismisses the Dialog and Displays Blank Plage

Tags: java, android

How To Call The Api Service Again on failure to Display the data, On Failure Will get A Blank Screen after the Progress Dialog Ends.

public void setSemesterData() {

```
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading..Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
    apiService= RetroClient.getApiService();
    Call<SemesterModel> call=apiService.getSemester(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SemesterModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SemesterModel> call, Response<SemesterModel> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();


            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {

                semesterList.clear();
                semesterList.addAll(response.body().getData());
                semesterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SemesterModel> call, Throwable f) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If you are using okhttp, it provides a `retryOnFailure()` method in the clientBuilder

Comment: Its Using Retrofit2